# how to left join one to many relationship to get count of child table with criteria builder in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Here Orders has customer, I want to get customer table along with count of orders for each record.
how to left join order table here? if customer has one to many relationship with order.

```
'*

Class customer{
 @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  int id;
  @Column(name = "id")
  String name; 
  @oneToMany
  List<Order> orders; 
}


*'
```

' *

```
 CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<CustomerView> q = cb.createQuery(CustomerView.class);
 Root<Customer> root = q.from(Customer.class);
 q.select((Selection<? extends CustomerView>) 
 Root<Order> orderRoot = q.from(Geofence.class) cb.tuple(root,cb.count(orderRoot.get("customer")).alias("orderCount")));
 q.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), orderRoot.get("customer")));
 q.groupBy(root.get("id"));
 TypedQuery<CustomerView> query = em.createQuery(q);
 List<CustomerView> results = query.getResultList();
```

*'

Comment: I wonder what any JPA docs would say about joining with Criteria? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_from_clause_joins

Comment: Could you rephrase you question please.